# 'Sampling' equivalent function in Calc

Tags: random, libreoffice-calc

Is there a 'Sampling' equivalent function (that is present in Excel) in Calc?

I would select a random subset of cells from a big set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Data -> Statistics -> Sampling`.

Documentation is at: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Data_Statistics_in_Calc#Sampling

Comment: It's not present in OpenOffice Calc 4.1.3 . It is an extension?

Comment: It's part of Calc.  Can you use LibreOffice?  If not, then try Data -> Subtotals, and under "Use functions" select one of the "Sample" functions.  Or try Data -> Consolidate with a "Sample" function.  Caveat: I have not tested either of these.

Comment: What do you mean with "Sample" function? There's not any function related to sampling, just Average, Var, etc

Comment: Well, I have not tested them, but it says "Var (Sample)" and "StDev (Sample)."  Anyway it looks like LibreOffice can do what you need.

Comment: It seems that with OpenOffice it doesn't work...but it definetely works with LibreOffice

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Analysis ToolPak and Analysis ToolPak VBA add-ins which have a sample method. Here's how you can [set it up](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ATP.htm)

you could then use it similar to below, however you may want to record a macro or review the function in object explorer to understand the parameters

`[atpvbaen.xls].Sample "Input range", "Output range", "R", "Sample size, e.g. 100"`

Comment: Analysis ToolPack is an Excel toolpack, but I use Calc